# Magento 2.4.2 #1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121

Tags: magento2

Hi friends after upgrading to magento 2.4.2, i received the following error in the product catalog.

I am also getting the message "There are no source items with in stock status" when trying to add an item to my cart

Has anyone had the same mistake? Or have you seen this error in previous versions?

[image: error catalog]

[image: There are no source items with the in stock status]

Comment: Take a look at your module Mageplaza/Shopbybrand. Disable it and check if the error still happen.

Comment: Erro foi corrigido desativando todos modulos msi inventory

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not a problem in the shopbybrand module because I tried to disable it and I still get the error "There are no source items with the in stock status"

[image: stock error]

Comment: Note All products are in stock